# After successfully installing Ubuntu, the old Windows OS unconditionally boots instead of Ubuntu

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, bios

I've recently tried to do a clean wipe of my old OS (Vista) on my spare PC and go with Ubuntu. I downloaded the ISO image and used Universal USB Installer-1.9.3.3 to format my USB stick for Ubuntu.

Despite a success dialogue and no errors, when I restart the PC and try to boot from the USB, the only thing that happens is that it boots into my current OS, and not the Ubuntu installer.

What can I do to boot Ubuntu?

Comment: Did you selected your USB as the first boot priority in your BIOS?

Comment: Are you running Windows 8?

Comment: It happen to me too. Try f12 for quick option. from there choose your desire drive from the lists and press ENTER. Hope it help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Answer (score 0):

Go into your BIOS (usually by pressing F2 on the manufacturer boot screen) and go into the "boot" section.
Move USB HDD to the top of the list and save.
If you still have your problem, check if your USB's ubuntu partition is flagged as boot.